# Jump function in box2d

Tags: android, ios, box2d, game-physics

I'm developing a game on Box2d world. I have player on screen and there is a ground body on bottom of screen.I wanna make "jump" function.I looked many examples but i couldn't find what i want.For now i use this:

```
void jump()
{
   float impulse = body->GetMass() * 10;
   body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(0,-impulse), body->GetWorldCenter() );
}
```

body is my player.But in this function, when i press jump button, it's jumping till i leave the button.I want: when i press button, it will jump 10px up and down back position.then i can press again.

Comment: Look [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability) and [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumping).